# Express endpoint not reflecting changes. Weird behavior

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have an express app that I am writing an API with, but currently experiencing some really weird behavior.

I made a change to one of my GET routes, and the changes are not being shown when I call that route. I use nodemon so the changes should update automatically, but even manually restarting the server does not work. I have tried the following things and have got really weird results:

- If I add a `console.log()` at the very beginning of the method, and then call that route, nothing appears in the console.
- If I completely remove the `app.get()` method and call that route, the response still pops up, not a 404
- If I change the name of the route (ex from "/hello" to "/helloWorld", the response continues to be the old one without the changes reflected. No matter if I call "/hello" or "helloWorld", I get the same old response from "/hello" I have been getting even though "/hello" shouldnt exist anymore
- If I change `app.get` to `app.post` and make a post request, the response now shows the changes that were made. But if I make a get request, the response reverts back to the old one even though this route should not exist anymore.
- Making changes to other routes DOES reflect when they are called. It is simply just this route.

Has anyone else ever seen any of this behavior? If so, what did you do to fix it?

I suppose I could just change the method to POST and have the request body be empty, but I would like to get it working how it should be with changes being reflected.

EDIT: Example route:

```
app.get('/hello', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    console.log("hello"); //added line
    pool.query("SELECT * FROM table", async (err: MysqlError, result: any) => {
       if (err) {
           res.status(500).send({ message: err.message, code: err.code });
           return;
       }
       res.send(result);
    });
})
```

In the code above, when I call the /hello route, I do not see "hello" printed to the console or any other changes that I make.

Comment: I can only guess what your code looks like.  Why not post code for a minimal app that reproduces this alleged GET route that is somehow immune to being changed?

Comment: Also -- it vaguely just sounds like caching.  What do the browser dev-tools say about what happened?

Comment: Hello Wyck - I added some code for you to see. I have tried making the calls in both postman and a regular browser, and both just show normal things. I also left out that changes I make to other routes DO show, it is simply just this route that is causing a headache.

Comment: Are you running the code you think you are?  Just start with [hello world](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html).  `curl localhost:3000` will return the hello message.  Then change the route from `/` to `/hello` and restart the app.  Then you should be able to demonstrate `curl localhost:3000` will return an error instead of the hello message and `curl localhost:3000/hello` will return the hello message.  You may have other code in your app that is causing the problem.

Comment: That all works correctly for me. In fact, it even works correct when I do that with other routes in my code. It's just this one route that is not working

Comment: Just change the handler so that it does `res.send('hello')`.  Then, do you have any wildcard routes, middleware, or caching?  If you changed the code so that you changed **both the route and the response text** from `hello` to `goodbye` and you still are able to get a client to receive `hello` (a string which should no longer exist in the server code) then you are facing a caching issue in the client.  If you are getting the new `goodbye` string but at the old `hello` endpoint, then you have middleware or other code causing the problem and you'll need to post it.

Comment: If I change the handler to ```res.send('hello')```, I still get back the old response I have been getting from before I changed the code originally. It seems to be stuck in a weird state that I cannot get it out of. This happens on any browser I try, even after cleared cache

Comment: I was able to figure out why this was happening. I will post an answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this was happening was because I had a route that was looking for a parameter (`/:id`) in the end point ABOVE this code. This meant the end point I was trying to hit was never getting hit because it would get stopped by the one above it and never continuing. To fix it, I simply had to move the route containing the parameter BELOW the one I was trying to hit.